# How to Redirect to another aspx page from javascript function at browser close event?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-chrome

Is it possible to redirect to another aspx page from javascript function at browser close event ?

Below is the code i followed but its not working..

```
  if (!e) var e = window.event; 
                {
                    if (e) {
                        alert("hi Chrome one");
                        //document.location.href = "http://www.google.com";
                        //window.location =  "http://www.google.com";
                  //window.location.href = "http://www.google.com";                       
                    }
                }
```

Can anyone give me the solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ii don't get it. If you're dealing with a close event,how are you going to redirect? You'll be closed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - you can use the body.unload event to do whatever you want - [here's an example](http://www.web-source.net/html_window_unload.htm) for opening a new window.

UPDATE: try this:

```
<body onbeforeunload="document.location='http://www.google.com'">
```

Hope this helps

Comment: already am using onbeforeonload  in body tag. can i use this also

Comment: what's "onbeforeonload"? You probably mean `onbeforeunload`! That's probably why your event is not firing...

Comment: yes onbeforeunload. its not firing even button click event in chrome

Comment: did you try the link I gave you?

Comment: yes. i tried this is <body onbeforeunload="doUnload()" onunload="window.open('http://www.google.com');" onkeydown="return DisableEnterKey()">

Comment: this works for me: `<body onbeforeunload="alert('unloading')">`

Comment: ok. but i want to redirect to another page from javascript function at browser close event only....

Comment: if this solved your problem (as it seems) please mark as Answer for the other members! Thanks